# Create ubuntu user on instance launch ansible aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am using ansible to launch aws instance. There is a default user on aws instance called "ubuntu" and I need to setup new user. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) is a guide to setup user manually, but is there any way to do it automatically via ansible?

Comment: Check this script you need to run this script in your playbook https://gist.github.com/martinhbramwell/4223476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another version, with this one you avoid using the **shell** module and instead use the native **user** module, the same thing for authorized_keys

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: Create user deploy
    user: name=deploy comment="The Deploy user" group=admin shell=/bin/bash
  - name: Copy deploy's authorized_keys file
    authorized_key: user=deploy key="your_authorized_key_file_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example playbook I wrote that does exactly that -

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host_name }}"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: Create user deploy
    shell: "adduser --disabled-password --gecos \"\" deploy10"
...
```

If need be, you can create a password user with slight changes to this playbook, and insert the authorized_keys part into this playbook. If you need any help with doing this let me know.

Comment: You should only be shelling out in Ansible as a last resort. Using Ansible's modules will allow you to more easily make your plays/roles idempotent without needing to use lots of trickery or registering and checking of task outputs.

Comment: You're right, I should've used the user module.. I've wrote this play that way because we specifically needed to use the `--disabled-password` flag and I couldn't find a way to do that with the user module. Thanks for the tip anyway.